# How to install JavaFX on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi

I want to run .jar file with JavaFX packeages on Raspberry PI 1 Model B.
JavaFX is not  included in JDK 8 version for ARM. Hence I tried to install JavaFX by reference to the following web site.
https://stackoverrun.com/ja/q/11146620

I succeeded to install JDK and move extracted files form a zip archive to JDK required folders.
I tried to run two .jar files after that. The GUI of one .jar file is consisted of Swing package, the other is consisted of JavaFX package.
The .jar file consisted of Swing package worked well, as shown in the following figure.
[Swing on Raspbian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MllfN.jpg)

On the other hand, the .jar file consisted of JavaFX package outputs errors or warnings as shown in the following figure.
[JavaFX on Raspbian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq401.jpg)

After these outputs, abnomal GUI without titlebar was desplayed. Consequently, minimizing, maxmizing/resizing closing and moving window are unable.
Additionally, surroundings of window is filled with black.
[Displayed window of JavaFX on Raspbian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D17v.jpg)

Of cource it is confirmed that these two .jar files worked well on Java 8 on windows 10 environment without errors.
[Swing on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzfWn.png)
[JavaFX on Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98h1L.png)

Note:As you know, Java 8 version for windows includes JavaFX libraries originally.

I want to solve this problem.
My current OS and Java information is shown below.
[Running Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PepdU.jpg)

Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.webtechie.be/post/2020-04-08-installing-java-and-javafx-on-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thanks. But I also tried the method. Both Java 11 and LibericaJDK requires Raspberry pi with ARMv7 CPU. So, this method can't be inapplicable to Raspberry PI 1 Model B.

Comment: As I recall JavaFX was included in Oracle's Java 8 but not in OpenJDK? You need to be careful not to break the license agreement or you can find yourself in trouble...

Comment: Does this run armv6? JavaFX11 from Gluon claims to have a version that runs on that. It requires JDK11 or later, so I think you’d have to build a version of JDK11; that’s probably a bit of a rabbit hole to go down but it may be a way forward...

Comment: To James_D : Unfortunately, The following error was output with JDK11.
"$ java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP"
Perhaps using Raspberry Pi 2 solve this, but I have lots of Raspberry Pi 1, and somehow I want to utilize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed almost all Linux JDKs for ARM now are for 64bit.

But Azul has a Zulu JDK you can start from: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-11-lts&os=linux&architecture=arm-32-bit-hf&package=jdk

```
$ cd /usr/lib/jvm
$ sudo wget https://cdn.azul.com/zulu-embedded/bin/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf.tar.gz
$ sudo tar -xzvf zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf.tar.gz
$ sudo rm zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf.tar.gz
$ ls -l
total 12
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   21 Jul 23 15:58 java-1.11.0-openjdk-armhf -> java-11-openjdk-armhf
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 4096 Aug 20 11:41 java-11-openjdk-armhf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 20 11:41 openjdk-11
drwxrwxr-x 10  111  122 4096 Jul 10 16:50 zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf

$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf/bin/java 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf/bin/javac 1

$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                                             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/java                       1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/java                       1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf/bin/java   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode

$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There are 2 choices for the alternative javac (providing /usr/bin/javac).

  Selection    Path                                                              Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/javac                       1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-armhf/bin/javac                       1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf/bin/javac   1         manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11.41.75-ca-jdk11.0.8-linux_aarch32hf/bin/javac to provide /usr/bin/javac (javac) in manual mode

$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.41+75-CA (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
OpenJDK Client VM Zulu11.41+75-CA (build 11.0.8+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Next step is installing JavaFX from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/ > "JavaFX armv6hf SDK"

```
$ cd /home/pi
$ wget -O javafx.zip https://gluonhq.com/download/javafx-11-0-2-sdk-armv6hf/
$ unzip javafx.zip
$ rm javafx.zip
```

When this is done, you can run your application with the following command:

```
$ sudo java --module-path /home/pi/armv6hf-sdk/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls -jar YOUR-APP.jar
```

For the full step-by-step, check this article on my blog: https://webtechie.be/post/2020-08-27-azul-zulu-java-11-and-gluon-javafx-11-on-armv6-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Thank you for telling completely new method. I am going to try your method this or next weekend.Please wait.

Comment: @TRI I got challenged by your question to finish a blog post I started working on a long time ago... ;-) so I was able to update my answer above with more info and include a link to the fully detailed step-by-step on my blog. Hope this helps you to solve your problem!

Comment: I'm Sorry to tell you late. I succeed to run my jar file with your proposed method. Thanks!

Comment: @tri happy I could help and thanks for accepting my answer!